# file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path when trying to set featured image

Tags: php, json, wordpress, function, instagram-api

I was trying to make a plugin which would get images from instagram API and then put them in shortcodes which would set the featured image in where the shortcode is. I have this code for the function for setting featured images:

```
<?php
function Generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

Then I have this code for getting the API and putting the images in an array :

```
//define Access token
$accesst= "3219594850.1677ed0.cb21f3e34b7c4030a8ba364d35ec284b";
//userid
$userid= 3219594850;
//image count to get
$count=20;
//get api contents
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$accesst.'&count='.$count);
//converting JSON to object
$standardres = json_decode($content, true);
//array method
$images= array();
foreach($standardres['data'] as $photo) {

   $imageData =file_get_contents($photo['images']['standard_resolution']['url']);
   array_push ($images, $imageData);
}
```

This should be the function which makes the post as a featured image:

```
//create functions for shortcodes with definition
function fone(){
    global $post;
    $fid = $post->ID; 
    global $images;
    Generate_Featured_Image($images[0], $fid);
} 
add_shortcode( 'one', 'fone');
?>
```

But I only get an error displaying :

```
Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in D:\XEMP\htdocs\xd\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\insta-live\insta-live.php on line 56

Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in D:\XEMP\htdocs\xd\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\insta-live\insta-live.php on line 60
...
```

Any ideas where did I go wrong? Line 56 and 60 is :

```
  $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
  file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
```

Comment: Have you tried this "$image_data = file_get_contents('$image_url', true);"

Comment: What happens if `$image_url` is not actually an image? Have you done `var_dump($image_url);` to see what your function is actually getting?